# Bootstrap absolutely positioned navbar will not lay on top of relatively positioned banner image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-position, navbar

I have a banner image that uses position: relative; inside of a wrapper with position: relative; I added a Bootstrap navbar-static-top. My goal was to get the navbar to lay on top of the banner image. So far I have tried changing the positions of some of the elements and despite my best efforts I still end up with white space between the navbar and the banner image. I believe it has something to do with one of the navbar classes that I'm using but I'm not sure which one. Below is the relevant HTML5 and CSS3 code.

```css
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

#banner {
 height: 50vh;
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
}

#responsive-nav {
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 60px;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mock Up</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                    <!-- Collapsing Hamburger Buttons for mobile -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>         
            </div>
            <!--Menu Items--> 
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="mainNavBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#work">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                 
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0B7B-ke12S7B2ZS1qSS1wOGJCVzg=w1046-h653-iv1">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="banner" src="https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0B7B-ke12S7B2SDRjaVpyY3FITFk=w1366-h653-iv1">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </nav>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/bd8b80bd9d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navbar` class in bootstrap provides margin-bottom:20px.  You can override margin-bottom, by making it important, to remove the space between navbar and image

```css
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

#banner {
 height: 50vh;
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
}

#responsive-nav {
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 60px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mock Up</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <nav class="my-class navbar navbar-static-top">
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                    <!-- Collapsing Hamburger Buttons for mobile -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>         
            </div>
            <!--Menu Items--> 
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="mainNavBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#work">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                 
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        
                <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0B7B-ke12S7B2ZS1qSS1wOGJCVzg=w1046-h653-iv1">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="banner" src="https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0B7B-ke12S7B2SDRjaVpyY3FITFk=w1366-h653-iv1">
            </div>
           
       
        
    </nav>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/bd8b80bd9d.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isnt it some what frowned upon to use 
  !important?

Comment: There was some mismatch in closing tags, that's why it was not picking the changes without using !important. I have updated your code in above snippet. If your css is being loaded before bootstrap css file, the styling in your style.css will override bootstrap styling.